# Use variable for type checking code in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have a code that a AnyVal type data f should be converted into Float/Double depending on the input parameter.

```
    if (n == 4) {
      if (f.asInstanceOf[Float].isNaN) None
      else Some(f)
    } else {
      if (f.asInstanceOf[Double].isNaN) None
      else Some(f)
    }
```

I tried to use variable to get this code, but I have an error.

```
    val t = if (n == 4) classOf[Float] else classOf[Double]
    if (f.asInstanceOf[t].isNaN) None
    else Some(f)
```

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`t` here has type `Class[_ >: Float with Double <: AnyVal]` because scala find the common super type to `classOf[Float]` and `classOf[Double]`, also as Alexey Romanov pointed out, `t` is a variable while `asInstanceOf` takes a type parameter, easy solution would be this:

```
val t: Option[Double] = 
  if (n == 4) Option(f.asInstanceOf[Float]) else Option(f.asInstanceOf[Double])
```

Which returns a `Option[Double]` since `Double` is a common supertype(*) to `Float`, for a more complex solution where you bring along the type in a variable I can't help you.

(*) it is not really a supertype but Scala has a view from Float to Double.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is a value, not a type, and the square brackets after `asInstanceOf` indicate it takes a *type* parameter. You can't have a variable type like this (there is such a thing as type variables, but they won't be useful here). One possible workaround is given in Ende Neu's answer; another would be

```
t.cast(f)
```

but this won't work here because you won't be able to call `isNaN` on the result.

Comment: I missed the variable part.